# How to show tiny MCE Widgets (Tools or -Icons in Toolbar) in frontend Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

im using the WP Emoji One Plugin, to give the user the chance to add emoticons to there Posts. This Plugin creates an icon in the tiny MCE toolbar. But its only appearing when the author is the admin in wordpress. While some other Plugins appearing for non logged in user as well. How can i change the code to also make this working for non logged in user??

And how to prevent some additional plugins to show up in Tiny MCE toolbar for non logged in user?

Comment: If you can please post the relevant parts of your code, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), others will be able to better help you.

Comment: @sinan , i know what you mean but this is a general question. i cant post the whole wordpress and tiny MCE code in here. neither the whole code of the Plugin im using, but thanks anyway